# Total variation integration of a discontinuous function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This question derives from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165950/why-does-maple-give-this-answer-for-the-total-variation-of-a-piecewise-function/2167314#2167314), about mathematics and *Maple*.

Consider the following discontinuous function:

```
f[x_] := 1 + HeavisideTheta[x - 2] + (Sin[π x] + 1) (HeavisideTheta[x - 2] - HeavisideTheta[x - 1])
```

[image]

Recall that the *total variation* of a function is:  $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \left| {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} \right | dx$.  Clearly this is non-negative and for the function just listed must be positive.  Nevertheless, when we compute this integral we find:

```
Integrate[Abs[D[f[x], x]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

(* 0 *)

Why?  Incidentally, the derivative itself is given as:

```
DiracDelta[-2 + x] + π Cos[π x] 
        (HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] -HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]) + 
        (DiracDelta[-2 + x] - DiracDelta[-1 + x]) (1 + Sin[π x])
```

If we use `Piecewise`,

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[
           {{1, x < 0}, 
            {Sin[π x], 0 <= x <= 1}, 
            {2, x > 1}}];
```

the total variation is given as

(* 2 *)

which is also not correct (as the cited question explains).  Presumably this is because *Mathematica* does a Riemann integral (effectively ignoring the indeterminate discontinuities).

Comment: If you look at D[f[x], x] for your piecewise function, you can see that the derivative has definition `Indeterminate` at the two discontinuities.

Comment: There are two problems here: (i) Taking the absolute of `DiracDelta` does not seem to work as expected and (ii) integrating `HeavisideTheta` gives zero. I don't know what to do about (i), unless you are willing to change signs manually. About (ii), you can replace `HeavisideTheta` by `UnitStep`, which has a numerical value at `x=0`, like this: `df[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]] /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep`

Comment: So I think the problem reduces effectively to "How take Abs of DiracDelta" or "How to solve `Integrate[Abs[DiracDelta[x]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`